# Excel Pivot chart with a legend summary table having SUM and COUNT of values

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, pivot-table

I have a pivot chart display some data I'm interested in. Using a summary table below the chart I can plot the SUM of the values. This works great for me since the data rows contains a `1` if I want to count the value and `0` if not.

Say I have 100 rows from which 20 are marked as 1 and 80 are marked as 0. At this point the pivot chart shows me `20` when I summarize the data using `SUM`. When I use `COUNT` it shows me `100`.

Is there a possibility to make it show `20/100`? To me this is interesting because I plot data over several categories in several years. For one given year and category `20` is scarce, for another it's a huge value.

Comment: If there is, I've never figured it out.